# Is it okay to insult gamers in your answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I refer to this answer:

> https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/121306/28015

The poster insults basically all modders out there and the moderators did not react so far.

I ask myself how this fits into the Q&A Format of this site and the rules?
I've edited the insults out of the answer, but it got rolled back. I then flagged it for moderator attention to avoid an edit war, but nothing happened so far. And this has been hours back.

Also, as per this topic:

> [Is it okay to heavily edit out subjectivity?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/is-it-okay-to-heavily-edit-out-subjectivity)

it is okay to edit out subjectivity. So I say that it is purely subjective if a modder is a jerk or not, if we don't see it as an insult.

Either way, I do not see this answer being a good fit for the sites format in this state.

What is the recommended course of action here?

Comment: Recommended course of action is exactly what you have done.  Now, @LessPop is one of our more valued members, and while he comes across as abrasive on occasion, his contributions are consistently high quality and valuable.

Comment: "Some" is not "basically all".  You're being disingenuous and, IMO, the language used was incredibly mild.

Comment: If you release something that is poorly documented, it is through ignorance and/or malice.  Hence, you are an idiot and/or jerk.

Comment: @MatthewRead +1 My (now removed) comment said pretty much that. Just less smartly. =P

Comment: So we remove "thanks" from posts but we allow insults? How does that make sense? Not to tell that I got banned for a minor insult too. So I don't see how that fits in. So does LessPopMoreFizz have a special status because he is longer here? Would be very hypocrite, don't you think? Not butthurt, just comparing.

Comment: Have you checked the flag in your profile?

Comment: @badp What flag?

Comment: It's none of your b---- er, I'm sorry I had to :-P the one you reference in the question. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/28015

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Regarding this case**, the insult itself doesn't contribute to the answer, and it *is* somewhat tasteless. And although honestly I'd probably feel this way if I just installed a promising mod just to find it completely undocumented, or spend hours trying to fix some compatibility issue caused by lack of documentation in some mod, I'd still try and avoid this kind of language.

**In the general case**, if harsh language or insults adds nothing to the answer, it's always better omitted. Unless you're referring to players who cheat in multiplayer games - in those cases, no insult is too bad and something extraordinarily cruel might even get you a bounty from me. Just sayin'.

Comment: Yeah. It is rather unnecessary. I realize that Lesspop has a few mods in mind that range from shoddy to shitty to tasteless to outright offensive, but that's besides the point. This question was about... all mods that add a weapon to the game ever and that's hardly identical to the group of mods that would elicit this language.

Comment: (Did I mention that the question he's answering shouldn't have been left open in the first place imvho?)

Comment: @badp Well… not all mods that add a weapon to the game are undocumented, yeah, but that category does include some of the worst of the worst for amateurish, buggy, broken, and undocumented. :) Glad to see it closed though: not reading docs is about as bad as not writing docs.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's obvious that mods, being more accessible and easy to build than full fledged games, occasionally come out worse in quality. But if you're asking the question, you probably have at least _one_ specific mod in mind.

Answer (score 6):

I would just like to interject as there has been a lot of fuss about this particular post. First of all, I would suggest that you [read it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/121306/revisions), since looking at your question you haven't actually read what was written, rather that you have read what you wanted to read.

Here is the contents of the post:

> The answer will be different for every mod. Most mods include some sort of documentation in a ReadMe file that will often (though not always! Some molders are idiots and or jerks!) tell you where to go in game to access the new content added by the mod.

Aside from the spelling mistake in the original post (which was fixed in later edits), I would like you to note that in this post there are a couple of really obvious things that you appear to have made assumptions about:

- You take this as an insult to gamers, when it is in fact referencing modders, the groups overlap, but are not the same group
- You state "insults all modders", the text clearly states "some modders"

From this, the information I want you to take away is that you shouldn't start twisting the context to suit your agenda.

In reference to your statement "Either way, I do not see this answer being a good fit for the sites format in this state" - the answer itself is fine, the fluff you're referring to is merely LessPop_MoreFizz being himself. The seven words that resulted in this drama do not positively or negatively affect the validity of the post and the post is neither better or worse off for having them or not.

They've been edited out now, as StackExchange is a collaboratively edited site, meaning we can all make edits that improve any post we have on here. No gamers were insulted in the creation of this post.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course. No gamers. Okay, then modders. Who cares about this difference? it is about Insults and not about the group. But then I can call Stack Exchange users assholes and it is okay, according to your definition :). And it had to be edited by a mod, because when I simply edited the offensive part, it got reverted. So collaborative editing does not count here. It would've ended in an edit war at best.

Comment: I'm still not convinced that you have read what I wrote... I also don't really see it as an insult, knowing LessPop_MoreFizz it's more playful banter. Either way - the seven words that you disagree with (a) don't invalidate the rest of his post and (b) no longer exist. Secondly, if any user regardless of who they are provokes an edit war, bringing it to meta or to the attention of a mod is the right action to take, but you should note that you removed more than just the insult and actually stripped out some useful information in your edit.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness You're still taking his message to mean "*all* modders," which he very clearly isn't saying.

Comment: @Fluttershy As being a modder myself, I take this serious. We dedicate free time in creating mods for you to enjoy and calling fellow modders "jerks and idiots" because they forgot or did not care for an extensive readme, for whatever reason, is not really polite as required by the Stack Exchange Rules.

Comment: At the end of the day - any modder (read: developer) that doesn't document their work deserves the criticism, maybe not in the same words, but they're certainly failing at a fundamental part of the development process. By stating "some" modders, LessPop_MoreFizz hasn't insulted modders in general, only the ones that are guilty.

Comment: I'm done. You refuse to read anything other than what you want to see, so I'm going to stop wasting my time trying to help you. *Some* != *All*.

Comment: No the real problem of this here is that you are protecting LessPop *(please do stop with the creative typos -badp)* because he is here a long time. If I would have written this or someone else relatively new to the site, it would have been down voted heavily, edited etc etc, the full program. But because it is someone who is known with a lot of karma, he is defended instead. Just being long here should not justify insults. Period. But that is the problem when the community is supposed to regulate itself, there is a lot of double standards and hypocrisy going on.

Comment: I'm going to ask you to stop intentionally spelling his name wrong, as *that* is being hypocritical.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness actually, if you ***read what I say*** I said the seven words in question didn't need to be there. Secondly, I hope that is a typo because you've raised a question about insults and posted a comment with an insult in it otherwise.

Comment: @none I have to agree with you there. We do cut regulars more slack and while in a way they've kind of earned it, it is true we would've gone the "full program" on a one Rep user.

Comment: @badp to be fair, if a 1 rep user had made exactly the same post, that user would have got a comment asking not to insult and it would have been edited out, which from where I'm sitting is exactly what happened in this instance as well. The only reason it ended up in a meta discussion in this instance is because somebody completely misread what LessPop_MoreFizz wrote.

Comment: @kalina Misreading "insulting some gamers" for "insulting all modders" for "insulting some modders" is _not_ a complete misreading. The insult is the operative word here. No matter the target, it's unnecesarry.

Comment: @badp like I already said, it adds nothing to the post.